# Listening to "call" event in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I would like to know if listening to the "call" event/activity is possible in Android. I would like to write a service that monitors the calls(outgoing) and other information regarding the calls(such as duration, target number etc) from an android device.

Example code snippets or skeleton code and other pointers would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The **TelephonyManager** class handles the Call events:

needed permission are:

```
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

And see this example (source code available):

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html

How to use Telephony manager effectively: [link](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/using-android-telephonymanager)